# How to input accented characters to an OS running in a VM?

Tags: unix, virtualbox, keyboard, input-source

I have a MacBook Pro with English (US) keyboard layout. I usually hold the right-alt (option) key, and press <kbd>E</kbd> to activate the accented vowel insertion (it shows a placeholder where the accented letter—`á`/`Á`, `é`/`É`, `í`/`Í`, `ó`/`Ó`, `ú`/`Ú`—would appear), and after pressing the corresponding vowel it will be inserted in place. Similar procedure using the <kbd>N</kbd> key to insert the `ñ`/`Ñ` characters.

I also have an Ubuntu Desktop computer with Latin American keyboard layout. Latin American Spanish keyboards have the acute accent character `´` right after the P key. In order to insert an accented vowel, you type first the acute accent, and then the vowel. Similarly to insert the `ñ`/`Ñ` characters, one would type the `~` character and then the `n`/`N` letter.

Everything fine until here.

The problem is when I have to run a Linux OS on a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox) on the Mac. I don't have the `´` character on the physical keyboard, and the right-alt (option) key doesn't have the same effect as in Mac OS.

The question here is, if there's a way to insert international (or at least accented vowels, which are the ones I mostly use) characters from the physical keyboard of the Mac, to the guest OS in the VirtualBox?

Comment: You may need to use the character map in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the keyboard layout in Ubuntu without any changes to OS X:

[image]

Then you can type like you would do on your Latin American keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Mine defaulted to the Spain keyboard setting. The Spain keyboard has the ñ/Ñ characters right after the L-key and the acute accent character one space after that: [L] [Ñ] [´]. The ñ/Ñ characters need no extra work In order to insert an accented vowel you would press the acute accent, then the vowel and release.